# How to mock the value returned from reading a properties file in jmock test

Tags: java, unit-testing, properties, jmock

I have a singleton java properties class (RepositoryProperties.java) that reads from a text file to get the value returned by the readFromSql method:

```
public boolean readFromSql() {
    String lPhase = getPilotProfileDatabaseTransitionPhase();
    if (lPhase.equals("PHASE_ONE_SQL")) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Then when I want to add a record via my repository implementation class, I have to check this value to know which code block to execute:

```
if (RepositoryProperties.getInstance().readFromSql()
      {
```

.. if true, write the data to SQL, else skip this block

Now I need to add a Jmock unit test for my repository add method such that readFromSql method returns true (another test will test the false value), without introducing a dependency on the text file.  I am afraid jmock is completely new to me and I can't figure out how to mock the value returned by readFromSql.  I don't have a setter method.

I tried adding an expectation for this, but it's not the correct approach (don't think this belongs in expectations) and my syntax is also wrong:

```
myMockContext.checking(new Expectations() {
{
        RepositoryProperties.getInstance().readFromSql();
        will(returnValue(true));
```

Would really appreciate a little guidance on how to do this properly and where.

Answer (score 0):

JMock is generally designed around the idea of mocking instances of interfaces. You *can* get it to mock instances of classes, although it's not recommended. What you're trying to do is even more than that - you want to mock a static method. That's very much against JMock's philosophy and Jmock will fight you every step of the way. You might want to look at alternative mocking frameworks such as [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) and [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) which have more flexibility to use mocks in situations where you don't have a clear test seam (i.e. an injected interface).

Also - the singleton pattern is fairly old school these days. Singletons implemented using the pattern create testing problems, like you're seeing, and genuine needs for singleton behaviour can generally be implemented using DI scopes more effectively. You might want to consider your need for a singleton in this instance - can you change it?